# Where can I find airspace maps for Turkey?

Tags: airspace, aeronautical-charts, turkey

I am trying to learn more about airspaces. It would be nice if I had the airspace map of my region to look and observe.

skyvector.com shows very few information about Turkey, not useful.

Comment: their government (the aviation department in particular) probably.

Comment: Overall you have the list of European countries [AIP at Eurocontrol](http://www.eurocontrol.int/articles/ais-online). Turkey [AIP is here](http://ssd.dhmi.gov.tr/ANSLogin.aspx?mn=50), but you need to have an account. I'd look at virtual aviation networks instead ([example](http://www.thyva.com/charts)). You may also use the [ICAO GIS viewer](http://gis.icao.int/icaoviewernew/#/29.5302/40.5747/10) (and select the type of map displayed).

Comment: Sounds like an answer, @mins, not just a comment! Have to admit, though, that "best source" is grounds for closure as opinion based, while "Where can I find..." is perfectly legitimate. ;)

Comment: Before providing an answer as suggested by @FreeMan, could you provide details about what kind of map you need, or if you don't know, maybe explain what you want to know, e.g. routes used in cruise, routes used to land at some nearby airport, etc.

Comment: You can always buy then from Jeppesen

Comment: Thank you @mins, I would like to see the airspace lines around airports like Class B, Class C, Class D.

Comment: @right-rudder As of a [2016 report by Eurocontrol](https://www.eurocontrol.int/sites/default/files/content/documents/official-documents/reports/LSSIP2016_TR_ReleasedIssue.pdf), Turkey has not yet implemented ICAO airspace classes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you need would be named "ICAO 1/500,000 map", this is a VFR map with airspace class, based on a [Lambert conformal conic projection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_conformal_conic_projection). Example in the US (1/250,000):

[image]

The best I can find online is SkyVector, but you said it's not sufficient for you needs:

[image]

By searching carefully you may find things like that:

[image]
[image]
(source: [University of Texas](http://www.lib.utexas.edu/maps/onc/))

But these are 1/1,000,000th very old maps from US DoD.

An alternative would be to use the online [GIS viewer from ICAO](http://gis.icao.int/icaoviewer/), selecting carefully layers and data to display, my trial at that:

[image]

It must be improved to suit your needs, but I don't expect it to be better than SkyVector. By clicking on a location, you can display all the information about relevant areas (description, limits, etc).

---

For enroute, [Eurocontrol](http://www.eurocontrol.int/articles/eurocontrol-regional-charts-erc) provide two maps:

- [High altitude](http://www.eurocontrol.int/sites/default/files/content/documents/nm/cartography/erc04h-31mar2016.pdf)
- [Low altitude](http://www.eurocontrol.int/sites/default/files/content/documents/nm/cartography/erc05l-31mar2016.pdf).

Good for intersection points and routes.

---

On the airport plates side, the [AIP for Turkey](http://ssd.dhmi.gov.tr/ANSLogin.aspx) is not in public access, but several sites provide plates, e.g.:

- [Turkish Virtual Airlines](http://www.thyva.com/charts) (static)
- [RocketRoute](http://www.rocketroute.com/weather.php?icao=ltac) (interactive)

[AirportNavFinder](http://airportnavfinder.com/airport/LTBA/) provides link to other sites like SkyVector.

[IVAO Turkey](http://www.ivaotr.org/) could be a good point of contact to discuss local documentation. They have a section Charts accessible to registered users.  - [VACC turkey](http://www.turvacc.org/pilots/air/ltba-istanbul-ataturk-int-l.html) is another virtual network.

If you can provide additional requirements, me or someone else may provide better material.

Comment: Dear @mins, by looking at the dashed blue lines overlay with thick faded blue lines, can we say these are Class D airspace and Class E airspace above 1200' AGL ?

Comment: Wow, great answer mins! @enginbulanık - if you have a new question, please ask a new one and don't attempt a long discussion of Q/A in the comments. Pull up the resource in question, create the map, get a screen shot & ask a whole new one - nobody will be upset about it at all, that's the way we do things at [StackExchange](http://aviation.stackexchange.com/tour)!